# finding indexes of 1's in a bit string and storing these indexes in a list -- Index should be started from 1 not 0

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am finding indexes of `1's` in a bit string successfully. However, these indexes start from `0`.

**Sample Data:**

```
initial_pop
000000000000000000000000000001011000000
000000001000000000000001000000000010000
000000000000000000000000000000010011000
000000000000001001000000000000010000000
000000000000000000010000001000000010000
1000000000100000000010000000000000000000
1000000010000000000001000000000000000000
1001000000000000000010000000000000000000
000000000000100000000000100000000000010
000000000110000000000000000000001000000
```

Now, If we look at the `6th, 7th, and 8th` data rows, values are placed at index 0 by default.

**My sample code:**

```
#Getting 1's index in a bit string
def intial_population(df_initial_pop):
    for ind in df_initial_pop['initial_pop'].index:
        msu_locations = indices(df_initial_pop['initial_pop'] [ind])
        initial_chromosomes_list.append(msu_locations)

#Calling function
intial_population(df_initial_pop)
```

**Output: (`print (initial_chromosomes_list`))**

```
[{32, 29, 31}, {8, 34, 23}, {34, 35, 31}, {17, 14, 31}, {26, 19, 34}, {0, 10, 20}, {0, 8, 21}, {0, 3, 20}, {24, 12, 37}, {32, 9, 10}]
```

As you can see in the above ouput, the index values are starting from `0`.

**Is it possible that I start my indexes from `1`?**

Comment: Why not add 1 to all indices when you get them ? msu_locations = {i+1  for i in indices(df_initial_pop['initial_pop'] [ind])}

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the initial data frame index by 1

```py
df_initial_pop.index += 1
```